# ASP.Net Core implementing recaptcha 2 on section of webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, recaptcha

I'm trying to add reCaptcha v2 to my ASP.Net Core website. There are around 30+ pages on the site and each page has a "Get in touch" form section at various points in the content.

I have a partial and a view model for this section which I include on each view:

**Partial call:**

```
@Html.Partial("_GetInTouchSection", GetInTouchViewModel)
```

**View model:**

```
public class GetInTouchViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your company name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your telephone number")]
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

A lot of the articles out there I've found talk around implementing this on a standalone page (such as feedback or contact us), posting back to the view's controller action and if the reCaptcha request fails, return the user back to the view.

[GitHub PaulMiami reCaptcha](https://github.com/PaulMiami/reCAPTCHA/wiki/Getting-started)

```
[ValidateRecaptcha]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(YourViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }

    return View();
}
```

https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2017/08/23/dotnet-core-mvc-recaptcha/#project

```
[HttpPost("Home/Feedback/")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Feedback(SomeModel model)
{
    // get reCAPTHCA key from appsettings.json
    ViewData["ReCaptchaKey"] = 
_configuration.GetSection("GoogleReCaptcha:key").Value;

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (!ReCaptchaPassed(
        Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"], // that's how you get it from the Request object
        _configuration.GetSection("GoogleReCaptcha:secret").Value,
        _logger
        ))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You failed the CAPTCHA, stupid robot. Go play some 1x1 on SFs instead.");
        return View(model);
    }

    // do your stuff with the model
    // ...

    return View();
}

return View(model);
}
```

Currently, my controller actions for each page are HttpGet only.

Instead of having a post action for each view, I was hoping to have one controller and action that I post the form to but I'm not sure if this is going to be possible.

```
    [ValidateRecaptcha]
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult PostGetInTouchForm(GetInTouchViewModel vm)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting PostGetInTouchForm routine");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _getInTouchService.SendGetInTouch(vm);
            ...redirect to thankyou page
        } else {
           ...what to do here? If I redirect, I lose the data posted
        }
        return View(vm);
    }
```

I don't know what to do on validation fail and how I take the user back to the GetInTouch section with what they entered? Alternatively, is there something I can do with AJAX to save posting the form until the reCaptcha has been validated or do I resign myself to the fact that I have to create a post action for each view and have to repeat the check and email code 30+ times?

Any help appreciated!